# Sitecore.Analytics.Automation - Does not exist in Sitecore 10.2

Tags: upgrade, migration

In `Sitecore 8.2` there is a dll named `Sitecore.Analytics.Automation` and it contains the below properties:

```
public class AutomationRuleContext : RuleContext
{
    public AutomationRuleContext();

    public AutomationStateContext ContactState { get; set; }
    public bool IsBackgroundUpdater { get; set; }
    public string PageEventName { get; set; }
    public PageEventItem PageEvent { get; set; }
    public Item StateItem { get; set; }
    public CurrentInteraction Visit { get; set; }
    public Contact Contact { get; set; }
}
```

and implementation is used as below:

```
public class MyClass<T> : WhenCondition<T> where T : AutomationRuleContext
```

Existing project Sitecore 8.2 is using
`public AutomationStateContext ContactState { get; set; }`
properties in the `Execute method`.

The `Execute` method is in the `WhenCondition` class as below:

```
public abstract class WhenCondition<T> : RuleCondition<T> where T : RuleContext
{
    protected WhenCondition();

    public override void Evaluate(T ruleContext, RuleStack stack);
    protected abstract bool Execute(T ruleContext);
}
```

does anyone have an idea about `AutomationRuleContext` and `WhenCondition`, where it's moved in `Sitecore 10.2`, and how can we use them in the **Sitecore 10.2 project while migration**?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sitecore.Shell.MarketingAutomation - Does not exist in Sitecore 10.2](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/32401/sitecore-shell-marketingautomation-does-not-exist-in-sitecore-10-2)

Comment: Both are different questions, this one is related to Sitecore.Analytics.Automation and another one is related to Sitecore.Shell.Applications. Someone edited the question title, I have corrected it again. Please allow the reopening of the question.

Answer (score 1):

Sitecore Marketing Automation has been completely rewritten since 8.2.

In Sitecore 9+ you need to write conditions which implement `ICondition` and `IContactSearchQueryFactory` interfaces

E.g.

```
public class PreferredCinemaMatches : ICondition, IContactSearchQueryFactory
{
    public string PreferredCinema { get; set; }

   // TIP: There are other operation types in theSitecore.XConnect.Segmentation.Predicates namespace
    public StringOperationType Comparison { get; set; }

    // Evaluates condition for single contact
    public bool Evaluate(IRuleExecutionContext context)
    {
        var contact = context.Fact<Contact>();

        return Comparison.Evaluate(contact.GetFacet<CinemaDetails>(CinemaDetails.DefaultFacetKey)?.PreferredCinema, PreferredCinema)
            && contact.Interactions.Any();
    }

    // Evaluates contact in a search context
    // IMPORTANT: Use InteractionsCache() facet rather than contact.Interactions as some search providers do not provide joins.
    public Expression<Func<Contact, bool>> CreateContactSearchQuery(IContactSearchQueryContext context)
    {
        return contact => Comparison.Evaluate(contact.GetFacet<CinemaDetails>(CinemaDetails.DefaultFacetKey).PreferredCinema, PreferredCinema)
        && contact.InteractionsCache().InteractionCaches.Any();
    }
}
```

More information in Sitecore docs here: https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/101/sitecore-experience-platform/create-a-custom-condition-and-segmentation-query.html