# Sitecore.Shell.Applications - Does not exist in Sitecore 10.2

Tags: upgrade, migration

In `Sitecore 8.2` there is a dll named `Sitecore.Shell.Applications`  and the namespace is `Sitecore.Shell.Applications.MarketingAutomation.Dialogs` and contains the below properties:

```
namespace Sitecore.Shell.Applications.MarketingAutomation.Dialogs
{
    public class EditorBase : DialogPage
    {
        protected NameValueCollection NvParams;

        public EditorBase();

        public Database CurrentDatabase { get; }
        public Item CurrentStateItem { get; }
        public Item CurrentEngagementPlanItem { get; }
        public virtual string Params { get; }

        public string GetParameterValueByKey(string key);
        public string GetParameterValueByKey(string key, string defaultValue);
        public void SaveParameters();
        public void SetParameterValue(string key, string value);
        protected virtual void ConfigureSaveParameters();
        protected virtual void Localize();
        protected override void OK_Click();
        protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e);
    }
}
```

The current project is using the below properties:

1. `protected override void ConfigureSaveParameters()`
2. `protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)`
3. `protected override void OK_Click()`

Does anyone have an idea about the above methods moved in `Sitecore 10.2`, and how can we use them in the **Sitecore 10.2 project while migration**?

Comment: Are you experiencing this with XM or XP?

Comment: Sitecore XP. The current project is in version 8.2 and needs to migrate to version 10.2. After upgrading Sitecore DLLs with version 10.2, I am facing this issue.

Answer (score 0):

`Sitecore.Shell.Applications.MarketingAutomation.Dialogs` that was present in Sitecore 8.x was removed in Sitecore 9.0 because the marketing automation engine was totally rebuilt. As such, any customisations you have will need to be rebuilt. The [docs](https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/102/sitecore-experience-platform/marketing-automation.html) contain information about how to customise it.